# Date Format Conversion - Robot Framework using Python

Tags: python, robotframework

Could some one help on this.

I am grepping a command in linux command to extract the date and getting this output.
grep -o '^20[0-9][0-9][^INFO]*' /opt/test/sample.log | head -n 1

This date needs to be formated in this format to : 20220404 15:38:46.983

Once linxu output date is formated, I need subtract the formated date with current date and check the difference.
For that writeen this logic.

```
  ${ConvertedDate}    Convert Date    ${output}
    Log    Current date in epoch format is  ${ConvertedDate}
    ${currentEpochDate}    Current Date in Epoch
     #Check the valiation of logrotation within the timeframe
    IF    '${ConvertedDate}' != '${EMPTY}'
        ${difference}    Evaluate    ${currentEpochDate} - ${ConvertedDate}
        IF    ${difference} > 600
             Run Keyword And Continue On Failure
             ...    Fail    Log Rotation not performed within expected 600s timeframe
        ELSE
            Log    Log Rotation performed within expected 600s timeframe: ${difference}s    TRACE
        END
    END
```

Could some one help on this.

Comment: by the way this is output of my grep command : 2022-04-04T12:05:09.356194+0200

Comment: Welcome to SO @SankarG Test4! Please provide a minimal reproducible example so others can better follow your problem and come up with an answer, thanks!